# Concatenating input to svn list command with output, then pass it to grep

Tags: unix, svn, grep, xargs

I currently have the following shell command which is only partially working:

```
svn list $myrepo/libs/ | 
xargs -P 10 -L 1 -I {} echo $myrepo/libs/ {} trunk |
sed 's/ //g' |
xargs -P 20 -L 1 svn list --depth infinity |
grep .xlsx
```

where `$myrepo` corresponds to the svn server address.

The libs folder contains a number of subfolders (currently about 30 although eventually up to 100), each which contain a number of tags, branches and a trunk. I wish to get a list of xlsx files contained only within the trunk folder of each of these subfolders. The command above works fine however it only returns the relative path from $myrepo/libs/subfolder/trunk/, so I get this back:

1/2/3/file.xlsx

Because of the potentially large number of files I would have to search through, I am performing it in two parallel steps by using xargs -P (I do not have and cannot use parallels). It am also trying to do this in one command so it can be used in php/perl/etc. and avoid multiple sytem calls.

What I would like to do is concatenate the input to this part of the command:

```
xargs -P 20 -L 1 svn list --depth infinity
```

with the output from it, to give the following:

```
$myrepo/libs/subfolder/trunk/1/2/3/file.xlsx
```

Then pass this to the grep to find the xlsx files.

I appreciate any assistance that could be provided.

Comment: It may be easier to use the `--xml` switch for the second `list` command and grab the full path at the top of the output of that and prepend it to all entries in the XML.  It would require an tool like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) though, which may be a dealbreaker.

Comment: Isn't `svn list $myrepo/libs/ | 
xargs -P 10 -L 1 -I {} echo $myrepo/libs/ {} trunk |
sed 's/ //g'` just a really obscure way to `svn list $myrepo/libs/ | 
sed "s%.*%$myrepo/libs/&/trunk%"` or am I missing something here? Is randomizing the lines important (which is the only reason for `-P 10` here I can come up with)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I manage to correctly divine your intention, something like this might work for you.

```
svn list "$myrepo/libs/" |
xargs -P 20 -n 1 sh -c 'svn list -R "$0/trunk/$1" |
    sed -n "s%.*\.xlsx$%$0/trunk/$1/&%p"' "$myrepo"
```

Briefly, we postprocess the output from the inner `svn list` to filter to just `.xslx` files and tack the full SVN path back on at the same time.  This way, the processing happens where the repo path is still known.

We hack things a bit by passing in `"$myrepo"` as `"$0"` to the subordinate `sh` so we don't have to `export` this variable.  The input from the outer `svn list` comes as `$1`.

(The repos I have access to have a slightly different layout so there could be a copy/paste error somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, the only small error was the "$0/trunk/$1" bit should've been "$0$1/trunk/"